# check whether more a selected or just a choice by checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 check that is run out of a foreach with the content. Thus, these checkbox tell my angularjs code of 0 is selected and if it is it should not be able to proceed to the next step.

I have tried to enter out about it gives success or error on that point.

Where the problem lies right now is: for example, it does not give me a message for error or success to you have selected one or more of the content.

index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var itemTypes in Model.ColorsAdd)
                {
                    <li class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="@itemTypes.img" class="img-responsive img-rounded mb-lg" />
                        <p class="label label-lg label-primary full-width">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   ng-checked="ItemSelectedColor"
                                   name="SelectedTypes"
                                   value="@itemTypes.Id" />
                            @itemTypes.Text
                        </p>
                    </li>
                }
```

angularjs-usercreate.js

```
$scope.UppersViewClick = function ()
{
    if ($scope.ItemSelectedColor.length >= 1) {
        console.log("succes")
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("error");
    }
}
```

Such here it appears on the page - is aware of it with the pictures but it's not what I'm looking at right moment.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use an ng-model instead? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, ItemSelectedColor will be true/false, not length >= 1...ItemSelectedColor isn't an array. If you want to check if there's something selected, you need to change your code.